# Selenium não encontra elemento

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

Segue o código. O selenium não encontra o elemento:

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class pages {
    static WebDriver navegador;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void abrirNavegador() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automacao\\chromedriverV36_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        navegador = new ChromeDriver();

        navegador.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        navegador.get("https://www.centraldacorrida.com.br/");

        navegador.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @Test
    public void paginaLogin() {

    navegador.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("C001104");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void posCondicao() {
        // navegador.close();
    }
}
```

Erro Trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"j_username"}
```

Answer (score -1):

fala carinha, blz ? ja tentou encontrar o elemento por xpath? 
por exemplo:

```
navegador.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@name='j_username']").sendKeys("C001104");
```